# Uniform Convergence of the series : $\sum\frac{1}{1+x^n}, x\ge0$

Tags: uniform-convergence

It is clear that the series converges uniformly on the interval $[a,\infty)$ , for $a>1$ as follows on using the Weirstrass M-Test as

$$\frac{1}{1+x^n} < \frac{1}{a^n}$$

Kindly suggest what about rest of the domain. My book says discuss the convergence and uniform convergence. I am confused how to discuss the two concepts in this example. Please help.

Comment: If $x\leq 1$ then the general term does not converge to $0$ and therefore the series converges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's denote $u_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^n}$ then it's clear that if $0\leq x\leq 1$ then $u_n(x)\not \to_{n\to\infty}0$ then $\sum_n u_n(x)$ is divergent and if $x>1$ then $u_n(x)\sim x^{-n}$ so $\sum_n u_n(x)$ is convergent by comparaison with the geometric series and hence the series $\sum_n u_n(x)$ is pointwise convergent on the interval $(1,+\infty)$.

Now if $x\geq a$ for $a>1$ we have
$$||u_n||_\infty\leq a^{-n}$$
hence the series $\sum_n ||u_n||_\infty$ is convergent then the series $\sum_n u_n(x)$ is normal convergent and then uniformly convergent on the interval $[a,+\infty)$.

**Recall** We have: the normal convergence implies the uniform convergence implies the pointwise convergence but the converse isn't true.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can you please suggest an appropriate text book to study the topic of uniform convergence.

Comment: @Tav You're welcome. I'm sorry because most of the books that I know are in French: the language of teaching in my country, yet I saw the book by Stephen Abbot Understanding analysis seems to me an excellent book.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. How do we define the concept of normal convergence for a series of functions ? Do you mean by fixing x, in the sense of series of real numbers ?

Comment: @Tav Here a link for more detail on the concept of normal convergence.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence